# WCF service method Implementation to Repository with multiple parameters

Tags: wcf

I'm trying to Setup WCF Service to create an entry in database table and return the same along with bunch of related data as Response of service.

I'm using EF with Repository Pattern to do all DataAccess work. Since the passing parameters are quiet huge list(15+).

Complex type (DTO) is much cleaner way of doing this?. or any other alternative for this.

I'm looking for cleaner and simple implementation...

more details...

1) Create DTO Object with all parameter info shared between Service side and Repository side.

```
    Public class RecordDTO
    {
     public string param1;
     public string param2;
     .....
     public string param15;

    }
```

2) Use DTO object to pass from Service method to Repository (both project should have  access to DTo)

```
   Repository.CreateRecord(RecordDTO myRecordObj)
```

3) Repository receives this and parse the data and do all sorts of DataAccess logic and return Model object passed back that understands service as well as Client.

I'm just exploring and trying to see whether this is possible.

Comment: Can you give us a concise example of the code that you are trying to improve?

Comment: for method like CreateRecord(param1,...............param15) in service implementation could be written with shared complex type library (DTO) on both service implementation & Repository side.

Comment: please edit the original question and included the formatted code.  Code in comments is difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can add CreateRequest dto, and encapsulate all parameters within. That is better for many reasons and some of them are:
- better readability 
- simpler method signature
- preventing breaking changes..

If these parameters must be saved with multiple repository method calles you can add transaction scope in your service method implementation.

I suppose that all these parameters are belong logically to this CreateRecord operation (one transaction). If they don't you can split this into multiple service methods..

Comment: It is single service method. But CreateRequest dto is for one way use only i.e (service to repository). The Response object would be POCO entities (EF code first model objects).